# Get Number of Sharepoint list view elements with javascript

Tags: javascript, listview, sharepoint, view

How I can get the counts list items of specific view ?
I want to get rid of the pivotControl-overflowDot, so all views a list have are shown without clicking on the dots.

I have the following code:

```
<script>
    function renderHeaderTemplateForDocuments(renderCtx, fRenderHeaderColumnNames){
        var viewData = eval(renderCtx.ListSchema.ViewSelectorPivotMenuOptions);
        ClientPivotControl.prototype.SurfacedPivotCount = 20;   
        return RenderHeaderTemplate(renderCtx, fRenderHeaderColumnNames); 
        var menu = $('ms-pivotControl-overflowDot');
        menu.style.display =  "none";
    }

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
      Templates: {
        Header: renderHeaderTemplateForDocuments
      }
    });
</script>
```

I don't know the numbers of elements and I set the SurfacedPivotCount to 20, 
but I want the SurfacedPivotCount to be dynamic, based on the number of view elements.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When customizing SharePoint list via CSR the number of available list view options could be determined like this:

```
var viewData = JSON.parse(renderCtx.ListSchema.ViewSelectorPivotMenuOptions);
var numOfViews = viewData.length - 3;  //system menu options such as Create View, Modify View and menu delimiter are exluded
```

**Example**

The following example demonstrates how to display all the available list view options

```
function renderHeaderTemplateForList(renderCtx, fRenderHeaderColumnNames){
    var viewData = JSON.parse(renderCtx.ListSchema.ViewSelectorPivotMenuOptions);
    var numOfViews = viewData.length - 3;  
    ClientPivotControl.prototype.SurfacedPivotCount = numOfViews;   
    return RenderHeaderTemplate(renderCtx, fRenderHeaderColumnNames); //render default Header template
}

SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
  Templates: {
    Header: renderHeaderTemplateForList
  }
});
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: This helped me! Thanks alot!